# Указать условия для класса

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Можно ли сразу указать условия для класса ?

```
:class="{ white : 20 == 20 }">
```

Иначе добавить класс **grey**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Например вот так:

```
v-bind:class="false ? 'first-class' : 'second-class'"
```

Также можно вызывать метод, тоже работает.